# Facebook login popup blocked from paper-button on-tap

Tags: facebook, polymer

I'm trying to use a paper-button to trigger a Facebook login (via the paper-buttons on-tap function and the Facebook Javascript SDK).

However, the on-tap method must be throwing away the 'click event', which means Chrome's popup blocker jumps in and blocks the Facebook login popup. If the popup is triggered from a 'user event' the popup is allowed to proceed.

Any ideas for telling the browser that the popup has indeed come from a user event?

**UPDATE:**

It appears to work as intended if I use on-click.